# How to display part of string if string contains special character

Tags: php, substr

I have following line of code,

```
echo substr('Sergio Agüero',0,10);
```

And it will display `Sergio Ag�`

But I want output like `"Sergio Agü"`

I don't want special character. So is it possible? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `mb_internal_encoding` and `mb_substr`.

Example: [online test](https://3v4l.org/rD0oC)

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$str = 'Sergio Agüero';
echo mb_substr($str, 0, 10); //Sergio Agü
```

More about: [mb-substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Thanks @Frayne Konok for give me such a great solution. I am really appreciate you.  :D

Comment: In my case I have one page and I have lots of name display on this page like this name, So can i have to set `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` in this page or where?

Comment: if you apply `mb_substr` in the page then you can use `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf8_decode. Try this:

```
echo substr(utf8_decode("Sergio Agüero"),0,10);
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working same output like my output.